# How to point multiple subdirectories to root web directory

Tags: php, apache, redirect

In my drupal web site I want to show filtered data based on user selected city. User can choose the city he belongs to (or intrested in) then I want to redirect him to mysite.com/cityname but it should point to the same webroot.

Is this possible?

Comment: sorry for that i am also searching for that how can we implement. i have only idea for that

Comment: You should use Apache Rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

htaccess file in your root directory and put following code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$          index.php?search=$1
```

And you can access you http://yourdomain.com/city-name

And you can get cityname in `$_GET['search']` parameter

I hope this will help you..

Thanks

Comment: These script was for PHP. I didn't use drupal. But Please check if there was url_rewrite module on your server  ??

Comment: do you mean mod_rewrite? yes I have it and enabled

Comment: http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/content/url/redirect  Check this link may be useful to you....

Comment: i want to point mysite.com/subdir1 mysite.com/subdir2 to mysite.com instead of redirecting mysite.com but seems like its not possible with this module

Comment: That was possible by above code but for drupal it may be some other configuration require. please read drupal documentation in its main site

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48682/discussion-between-pratiksha-raikundaliya-and-noob-as-three-developer)

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?city=$1 [L]
```

To a user on your site, they will see and navigate to this:

```
http://example.com/city
```

But the real page would be something like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?city=usercity
```

Comment: you should have mentioned before that it is a Drupal site

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that earlier